# HorizontalPager Images are not in equal size in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I want to make same Image size in all pages of `HorizontalPager`. I am manually added size in `Image` and it looks perfect. I want to remove the specific size, so is it possible to do in jetpack compose?

```
HorizontalPager(
    count = 5,
    state = pagerState,
) { currentPage ->
    Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
        Column(
            Modifier.height(height = 428.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(280.dp)
                    .padding(top = 80.dp),
                painter = painterResource(imageResId),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
            )
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 20.dp),
                text = "Xyz",
            )
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 20.dp),
                text = "description",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            )
        }
        HorizontalPagerIndicator(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = 80.dp),
            pagerState = pagerState,
            activeColor = Teal,
            inactiveColor = Platinum,
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Image` uses intrinsic size of `Bitmap/Painter`, parent `Constraints` or dimensions in simple manner and `ContentScale` to draw a resource.

Based on image resource aspect ratios they are to be fit inside an `Image` constrained with 428.dp minus size of other `Text` composables, this is the biggest height `Image` can get based on its inner calculations. Simple solution for this is to match one dimension of Image to parent and using Modifier.aspectRatio to have all images have same dimensions without setting a fixed size modifier.

These 2 png files have different aspect ratios and drawn as

[image]

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun Test(){
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp).border(2.dp, Color.Red)) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.landscape11),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
            )
        }

        Column(modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp).border(2.dp, Color.Green)) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.landscape3),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
            )
        }
    }
}
```

After setting aspect ratio modifier

[image]

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun Test(){
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp).border(2.dp, Color.Red)) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.aspectRatio(4/3f),
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.landscape11),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
            )
        }

        Column(modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp).border(2.dp, Color.Green)) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.aspectRatio(4/3f),
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.landscape3),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
            )
        }
    }
}
```